# Latest sports headlines in Latin: "Manchester City gets the first place"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, sentence-translation

I want to translate the sentence "Manchester City gets the first place" to Latin, in a sports headline kind of context.

I roughly did it as "Manchester Urbe primum positionem tenet".

The Urbe part is just a joke, but is "primum positionem tenet" right?

NOTE: May look as homework but it's not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nearly correct, but *positio* is feminine, so it should be *primam positionem tenet*.

I feel that it's all a bit fancy, or even too indirect for a footballing context. I wouldn't say 'gets first place' : after all, it's not a race. You could try *Partes Urbis Mancuniae vincit*, literally '[the team] of the City [of] Manchester wins'. To show that MC leads the Premiership, *Partes Urbis Mancuniae primarium cursum ducit*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me at *positio* gender, totally missed that. But what you propose reads too much as if the team just won the last match, not that it's now in the first place in league - probably I should have added the "in league" part.

Comment: Then you want not _vincit_ but _primarium cursum ducit_. I'll modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks again, and excuse my ignorance but, does *primarium cursum* mean "Premier League"? I hope so, this made me laugh so much :)

Comment: @Rodia In a word, yes.

Comment: Is _Mancuniae_ right? I figure that _Mancunium_ might be feminine, but wouldn't it still decline like any other 2nd-declension noun? Also, wouldn't it be better to use an adjective: _Urbis Mancuniensis?_

Comment: @Ben Kovitz You can take your pick with this one. Of all the variations I've seen here and elsewhere, I like _Urbs Mancunia_ best,(_cf Urbs Roma_), but I'm happy enough with _Mancuniana_. If you google either 'mancunium' or 'mancunia' you'll see what I mean — especially when it comes to City vs. United!

Comment: @TomCotton Thanks! It looks like I was quite wrong about _Urbs Mancuniensis._ In fact, now I'm going to remove that from my answer just so it doesn't spread…

Answer (score 5):

If you mean that Manchester City just moved into first place:

> Urbs Mancunium locum primum capit.

Background: [Manchester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester#Name) was founded by the ancient Romans in 79 A.D. They called it *Mamucium* or sometimes *Mancunium.* The latter seems to have won out. [Vicipædia](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mancunium#Cultura) gives *Mancunium Urbs* for the name of the football team, but I think *Urbs Mancunium* follows Latin custom a little better (also used by Vicipædia [here](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alanus_Mathison_Turing#Urbs_Mancunium)).

I didn't find clear-cut precedent for a Latin expression for "first place" in a contest or race, but I did find some where *locus primus* indicates the most prestigious position, so it seems right. *Positionem primam* is probably fine, too, as is *tenet.* *Tenet* is probably better if you just mean that Manchester City is in first place, not that they just got there.

If this is very big news and you want to go all-out Roman, either on stone or newsprint, you could make the headline:

> VRBS·MANCVNIVM·LOCVM·PRIMVM·CAPIT

If in doubt, you should take Tom Cotton's suggestion over mine. I'm just a little past the beginner stage and getting this from dictionaries and searches. Tom's got a genuine feel for the language from extensive use.

Comment: This is very useful too, thank you. Taking note of adjective place in *Positionem primam*, sounds way better than what I was using.

Comment: _pace_ Wikipedia, "urbs mancunii" strikes me as much more idiomatic than "mancunium urbs"